# Handling PointerReleased events in Flipview

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to create an application containing a flipview that automatically flips to the next page when the user hasn't interacted with it for a while. This works fine using a basic DispatcherTimer that gets restarted when the flipview's selection changes.

So far so good, but I also don't want the timer to run when the user is interacting with the current item in the flipview, like a listview or something. I figured that I could just wire up a PointerPressed and PointerReleased handler to the page and stop the timer whenever a pointer is pressed, and restart it when a pointer is released.

This works, except when the pointer is on the flipview: the pressed handler gets executed, but FlipView gobbles up all the other pointer events, so the PointerReleased handler never gets executed.

I can't figure out how to get this to work. In WPF, I'd just use a tunneling event, but that whole concept seems to have disappeared with WinRT? Any advice on how to get this to work?

**Update with code**

Sure. I have a page containing a flipview and a dispatchertimer:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private DispatcherTimer slideScrollTimer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        // Set up a timer that'll flip to the next page every 5 seconds.
        this.slideScrollTimer= new DispatcherTimer()
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
        };

        slideScrollTimer.Tick += slideScrollTimer_Tick;
        slideScrollTimer.Start();
    }

    void slideScrollTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        // When the timer runs out, go to the next page, or back
        // to the first.
        if (flipView.SelectedIndex < flipView.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            flipView.SelectedIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            flipView.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private void flipView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // restart the timer if someone flips to a different page
        if (this.slideScrollTimer != null)
        {
            this.slideScrollTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what I want is for the timer to reset whenever someone touches the application. I tried adding a PointerPressed/PointerReleased handler using AddHandler, but released only fires if you're not on the flipview, or just tapping it instead of scrolling it or manipulating its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`UIElement.AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.addhandler) to handle events that have already been marked as handled elsewhere.

> Adds a routed event handler for a specified routed event, adding the handler to the handler collection on the current element. Specify *handledEventsToo* as **true** to have the provided handler be invoked even if the event is handled elsewhere.

Comment: That only causes the PointerReleased event to fire if you tap. If you touch, move, and release, it still doesn't fire.

Comment: I had similar problems on the project I'm currently working on, but to have a better idea of the solution, I'd have to see some of your code.

Comment: any update on this situation? I'm having this problem in windows phone 8.1